# How to concatenate parameters before a ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, concatenation

This works:

```
$('#someId').live('click', function() { 
    var myData = '{ Periode: "something" }'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Nyhedsbrev/SendMailKunTilMig",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: myData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

This dosn't work, when I try to concatenate it, what can I do? It's nessesary to learn because I will later have many parameters.

```
$('#someId').live('click', function() { 
    var dataConcatenate = "something";
    var myData = '{ Periode: ' + dataConcatenate + ' }';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Nyhedsbrev/SendMailKunTilMig",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: myData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the string you are sending to the server isn't JSON, that's likely why it is failing.

Comment: The first example isn't valid JSON either, your server-side JSON parser must be loose. (`Periode` **must** be in `"` to be valid JSON.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var myData = 
{
    Periode: dataConcatenate,
    Param2: data2
}
```

Then call `JSON.stringify` in the Ajax call:

```
data: JSON.stringify(myData),
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks So that's when you use stringify huh :)

Answer (score 1):

`{ Periode: dataConcatenate }`

Without the use of **'**

Comment: No, because the OP isn't using the default `contentType`.